# Calclulating and creating x matrix using set.seed function

Tags: function

1. I have been asked to evaluate the sum of xi's? what could be wrong with the following code? How to correct it to work?

set . seet (1) #set random seed
x = rnorm (50)
for ( j in 1:50){ s = s + x [ i ] }

2. Also, if you are calculating the sum of xi's and xj's using seed function for i = 1...20 and j = 1,2. what could be wrong with the following code?

set . seed (1) #set random seed

## create x matrix

x = matrix ( rnorm (40) , nrow =20 , ncol =2)
S = NULL
for ( i in 1:2)
{
for ( j in 1:20)
{
S <- s + x[i , j ]
}# end of j loop
}# end of i loop
(c) Calculate the row means

Comment: Welcome to Cross Validated! // Why is a seed coming up at all? Why are you using loops instead of built-in functions like “sum”? // Please format your code so it can be read and copied verbatim into R to be run.

Comment: It seems you are to _generate_ the $X_i$.s and then to sum them. What is the distribution of the $X_I$s? What is the the purpose for finding the sum?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want the sum of two standard normal random variables, and to repeat this task 40 times, then here
are two methods that give identical results for the same seed:

```
set.seed(1)
x = rnorm(80)
MAT = matrix(x, nrow=40)
head(MAT)  # first six rows of matrix
           [,1]       [,2]
[1,] -0.6264538 -0.1645236
[2,]  0.1836433 -0.2533617
[3,] -0.8356286  0.6969634
[4,]  1.5952808  0.5566632
[5,]  0.3295078 -0.6887557
[6,] -0.8204684 -0.7074952

s = rowSums(MAT)  
summary(s)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-3.3441 -0.3653 -0.0317  0.2123  1.0424  3.3206 
 s
 [1] -0.790977407 -0.069718356 -0.138665237  2.151944001
 [5] -0.359247923 -1.527963541  0.852011015  1.506857630
 [9]  0.463435140  0.575719339  1.909887049 -0.222183157
[13] -0.280120889 -3.344062983  2.557954620  1.935466289
[17] -0.383411740 -0.100298416  1.390940823  0.458846717
[21]  3.320595132  0.742896298  0.764304346 -1.961349537
[25] -0.123447461  0.132663560 -1.960754136 -0.005197522
[29] -0.324896717  2.590553231  1.834189080 -0.812734158
[33]  0.998397965 -0.987902672 -2.630692957 -0.123548328
[37] -0.837581827 -0.058208045  1.174366696  0.173654802
```

.

```
set.seed(1)
x1 = rnorm(40); x2 = rnorm(40)
head(x1)
[1] -0.6264538  0.1836433 -0.8356286  1.5952808
[5]  0.3295078 -0.8204684
head(x2)
[1] -0.1645236 -0.2533617  0.6969634  0.5566632
[5] -0.6887557 -0.7074952

s = x1 + x2
summary(s) 
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-3.3441 -0.3653 -0.0317  0.2123  1.0424  3.3206 
head(s)  # same forty sums as above; only six shown
[1] -0.79097741 -0.06971836 -0.13866524  2.15194400
[5] -0.35924792 -1.52796354
```

Here is another method that uses the random variables
is a different order, and so gives a different simulated
result starting with the same seed.

```
set.seed(1)
t = replicate(40, sum(rnorm(2)))
summary(t)
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
-2.8359 -0.4970  0.1051  0.2123  1.1563  3.4134 
length(t)
[1] 40
```

Notice that the 'Mean` is the same as before because
the same 80 observations are involved, even if in a different order.

```
head(t)
[1] -0.4428105  0.7596522 -0.4909606  1.2257538
[5]  0.2703930  1.9016244
```

*Notes:* (1) You can show code and output here by beginning
each line with four blank spaces.

(2) Your question is about R, not really about statistics, so I suppose it may be closed or 'migrated' to another site. If I have not correctly guessed what you're trying
to do, please clarify the question.

Comment: This is really what I wanted and thanks for your help. Indeed R programming is demanding task and at the same time highly rewarding.  Many thanks BruceET for your help.